# One legend with same scale tmap

Tags: r, legend, tmap

I want to make a graph by[image] combining several maps, as shown in the attached image. But I need to create one legend (not four as shown) and also want to vary between 0 to 100. 
I think it is possible, any suggestion in this regard would be great.

### Del

```
d_dw <- tm_shape(d_pcahlsp) + tm_fill("dw_twts", breaks=c(0,10, 20, 30,40,50,60, 70, 80, 90, 100), Palette = "Reds", 
                              title = "% Treated drinking water") +
        tm_borders(alpha=.4) +
        tm_layout(legend.text.size = 0.8, legend.title.size = 0.8, frame = FALSE, legend.outside = TRUE, 
                  title = "Delhi")
```

### Luk

```
l_dw <- tm_shape(l_pcahlsp) + tm_fill("dw_twts", breaks=c(0,10, 20, 30,40,50,60, 70, 80, 90, 100), Palette = "Reds", 
                              title = "% Treated drinking water") +
        tm_borders(alpha=.4) +
        tm_layout(legend.text.size = 0.8, legend.title.size = 0.8, frame = FALSE, legend.outside = TRUE,
                  legend.show = TRUE, title= "Lucknow")
```

### Mad

```
m_dw <- tm_shape(m_pcahlsp) + tm_fill("dw_twts", breaks=c(0,10, 20, 30,40,50,60, 70, 80, 90, 100), Palette = "Reds",
                                      title = "% Treated drinking water") +
        tm_borders(alpha=.4) +
        tm_layout(legend.text.size = 0.8, legend.title.size = 0.8, frame = FALSE, legend.outside = TRUE,
                  legend.show = TRUE, title = "Madurai")
```

### Tri

```
t_dw <- tm_shape(t_pcahlsp) + tm_fill("dw_twts", breaks=c(0,10, 20, 30,40,50,60, 70, 80, 90, 100), Palette = "Reds", 
                                      title = "% Treated drinking water") +
  tm_borders(alpha=.4) +
  tm_layout(legend.text.size = 0.8, legend.title.size = 0.8, frame = FALSE, legend.outside = TRUE,
            legend.show = TRUE, title = "Thiruvananthapuram")


tmap_arrange(d_dw, l_dw, m_dw, t_dw, ncol = 2)
```

Comment: You made quite an effort with your question, why don't you add some data to enable us to replicate your issue? Read her how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610

Comment: It is a huge dataset and I am not aware of how to share with the group. I think this can be performed on any 2 maps, not necessarily on the above dataset. Many thanks, Jay!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a "categorical" variable to each `sf` object 
(e.g., d_pcahlsp$place = "Delhi") , bind them with `rbind` 
and then make a faceted tmap using `+ tm_facets("place")

Demonstrting here with the`nc` dataset:

```r
library(tmap)
library(sf)

# create replicates of the nc dataset
nc <- st_read(system.file("/shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
nc_2 <- nc
nc_3 <- nc
nc_4 <- nc


# add categorical variable to distinguish "panels,
# and modify the AREA column to see variations
nc$place = "1) Here"

nc_2$place = "2) There"
nc_2$AREA = 1.3 * nc_2$AREA

nc_3$place = "3) And"
nc_3$AREA = 1.1 * nc_3$AREA

nc_4$place = "4) Everywhere"
nc_4$AREA = 0.6 * nc_4$AREA

# bind the datasets
nc_tot <- rbind(nc, nc_2, nc_3, nc_4)

# plot
tm_shape(nc_tot) +
    tm_polygons("AREA") +
    tm_facets("place", ncol = 2)
```

[image]